# Primefaces dataTable with embedded commandLink

Tags: java, xhtml, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to embed a Primefaces commandLink and call an action listener from a link inside a column of a Primefaces dataTable.  Is this not possible?  The "Test" onclick alert gets fired but it never makes it to my bean's method.

```
<p:dataTable var="location" value="#{adminBean.locations}">  
        <p:column headerText="Options">  
            <p:commandLink value="delete" actionListener="#{admin.deleteLocation}" onclick="alert('test')"/>
        </p:column>    
    </p:dataTable>
```

bean code:

```
public void deleteLocation(ActionEvent e){
   //delete logic here...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [commandButton/commandLink/ajax action/listener method not invoked or input value not set/updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/commandbutton-commandlink-ajax-action-listener-method-not-invoked-or-input-value)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possible. Your actionListener should be called. Keep in mind that the `p:commandButton` uses ajax by default. So you should use the `update` attribute in order to define the components to be updated.

However, I don't know if this affects the actionListener. Did you try it with `action` instead of `actionListener`?

Here is an example how I got it working:

```
<p:commandLink action="#{spc.selectPatient(item)}"
               ajax="false"
               value="Open"/>
```

The bean method looks as follows:

```
 public String selectPatient(Patient p) {
    // do something
    // return some outcome
 }
```

Comment: I'll give yours a try but I also see this example...http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowSelectionByColumn.jsf